# padding issue in NetworkImageView on navigation header

Tags: android

I have implemented code for navigation header where I am using one **NetworkImageView** and image is shown with `padding 10dp` on left side my issue is I used `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` but it's not working on **lollipop, marshmallow version**. I run my app on kitkat version then the image has left padding with center vertical. Please tell me where I am wrong?
[image: ![enter image description here]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
android:background="#e6e3e3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/tv_email"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Reg Date : "
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/reg_date"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_email"/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="10dp"
android:id="@+id/tv_reg_date"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reg_date"
android:layout_below="@+id/tv_email"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastlogin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/reg_date"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Last Login : "
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/last_login"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lastlogin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_reg_date"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Membership : "
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/membershipStatus"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lastlogin"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/tv_status"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/membershipStatus"
    android:layout_below="@+id/last_login"/> 
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This pbm is that you are fixing width and height.It's not version 5.0,6.0 problem...so you have to set proper wight for layouts.

Comment: May it's occur because of your style of Actionbar  please try to put <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>   in your style hope it may work for you !

Comment: post your navigation header xml coding

Comment: post your full xml code

Comment: I hav updated full code please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your layout file. Its not version issue.